# Calculating number of occurrences of a character

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I export data from an application to Excel sheets.

The first column of the exported data (Column A) has some information, but contains text like `16.1` or `16.1.1`, etc. I need to create a column right next to it, containing the "level", which is calculated by the number of dots.

For example, for `16.1.1` the level is 2, or for `16.1.3.4` the level is 3.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following formula to count the `.` in the cell.

`=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))`

Copy the formula to the rest of the cells in the column to get result for each row.

[image]